# Swift: custom tableView cells that need to update each other's Switch settings

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I've been banging my head against what I thought was a straightforward bit of code for days.

I've got a dynamic tableview with a custom cells containing a UISwitch.  I need to make it so these cells have a dependency that they cannot both be 'on'  at the same time (i.e. they can be: off-off, off-on, on-off, but not on-on).

I've got a simple closure linked to a 'toggled' action that updates the flags in the underlying data structure, and I've verified this works as expected.

However I can't get the UI to update to show the dependent changes, i.e. if I toggle flag1 to on, it sets flag2 to off but it won't change the switch linked to flag2 to off.

I've tried both doing this in the triggered action closure and by using property observers on the variables in the following way, but the switch in the UI is never updated as I would expect it to be.

```
var flag1 = true {
      didSet { 
         print("flag1 set to \(flag1)")  //always prints expected value
         let indexPath = IndexPath(row: flag1Details.row, section: flag1Details.section)
         if let flag1Cell = tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as? SwitchCell {
            flag1Cell.rightSwitch.setOn(flag1, animated: true)  //also tried setting .isOn = flag1
         }
      }
   }

   var flag2 = false {
      didSet {
         print("flag2 set to \(flag2)")  //always prints expected value
         let indexPath = IndexPath(row: flag2Details.row, section: flag2CellDetails.section)
         if let flag2Cell = tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as? SwitchCell {
            flag2Cell.rightSwitch.setOn(flag2, animated: true)
         }
      }
   }
```

Strangely I've mocked this up using static cells and I can set the values of the switches without any problems using IBOutlets, so I guess it must be related to how I'm identifying\accessing the dynamic cells?

Am I making an obvious mistake that I'm blind to, or is there some nuance of dynamic tableView cells that I'm not aware off?  I'm sure this must be straightforward, but I'm not seeing it!  Thanks for any pointers...

Comment: Try to add tableview.reloadData() after setting the flag, I think when you modify a dynamic cell you have to reload the data of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the thought Pablo, but already tried that (and reloading the individual row) but no luck.

Comment: But just tried it again, to be sure, and it now seems to be working!  I'll have another coffee and think about it again!!   Thanks.

Comment: No worries :), this problem happened to me too :), if you modify dynamic cells you have to reload all the table. If after reloading all the table it is not working is because you are not setting it right. I mean in the table reload maybe you are setting it again to de Off value